# Why does this program compile but not display any output?

Tags: c++

```
 # include < iostream >

int return33()

{
    return 33;

}

int return213()

{
    return 213;

}

int main(){

   return33();

   return213();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does not call any functions to display anything.

Comment: The `return` statement does not cause anything to be printed. It's merely a mechanism for a function to return a value to the calling code.

Comment: Why do you think it should display anything?

Comment: You need  to call  cout

Comment: Unless you explicitly print something, then nothing will be printed.

Comment: Use `std::cout<<return33();` in your main function.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it? The C++ standard allows you to write a program that does not consume any input or generate any standard output.

But note that your program *does* return 0. In that sense, it does do something.

A reasonable compiler will optimise your program to `int main(){}`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just returning the values.You need to print the values in order to view them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not have any print statement therefore output is not printed use this program

```
#include<iostream>
int return33()
{
     return 33;
}
int return213()
{
     return 213;
}

int main(){
     cout<<return33()<<endl;
     cout<<return213();
     return 0;
}
```